# Find first element above other element using Playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I have a div with text, for example 'abc'.

I wish to find the first div above that element that has a class called 'myClass'. How to do it? My code doesn't work:

```
self.page.locator(f'[class="myClass"] >> nth=0:'                                        
f'above(:text("abc"))').count()
```

[image: Image example]

Comment: can you add the html ?

Comment: @AlapanDas I add a picture

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @AlapanDas Find the first div with class "topic-wrap" that is above the text "Security"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
self.page.locator(f'div:above(:text("Security Notifications"))').count()
//or
self.page.locator(f'div:left-of(:text("Security Notifications"))').count()
//or
self.page.locator(f'div:near(:text("Security Notifications"))').count()
```

Comment: No, this is not giving me a count of 1, I get 0